# How to generate a PDF file and upload it to Google Drive from a Flutter web application?

Tags: flutter, pdf, google-drive-api

I'm developing a Flutter web application and I need to dynamically generate a PDF file on the client side and then upload it to my Google Drive account. Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or an example of how to achieve this using Flutter and the Google Drive APIs?
my code:

```
  final pdf = pw.Document(
    pageMode: PdfPageMode.outlines,
  );

  final img2 = await rootBundle.load(paths.headerPdfPng);
  final imageBytes2 = img2.buffer.asUint8List();
  pw.Image image2 = pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(imageBytes2));


  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Column(
          children: [
            pw.Container(
              alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              child: image2,
            ),
            ])
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );


  final pdfBytes = await pdf.save();


  final creds = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "sumando-talentos",
    "private_key_id": "MY_PRIVATE_KEY",
    "private_key":
        "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----HERE MY DATA=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "sumandoweb-729@sumando-talentos.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "MY_ID",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url":
        "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/sumandoweb-729%40sumando-talentos.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
  });
  final client = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(creds, [drive.DriveApi.driveScope]);


  // Upload PDF to Google Drive
  final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(client);
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media"),
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer ${client.credentials.accessToken.data}",
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/pdf",
    },
    body: pdfBytes,
  );



  final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
  final fileId = responseData['id'] as String;
  final webViewLink = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/$fileId/view';
  final downloadLink = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=$fileId';
  print("Viewing link: $webViewLink");
  print("Download link: $downloadLink");
  client.close();
```

**I Recibe a Status 200, but when i was going to mi Google Drive Account is empty**